# Install4j installer for Linux shows logs on the console when run from terminal

Tags: install4j

On initializing the linux install4j installer from terminal it shows logs in the background while installation GUI pops up. Could somebody suggest me what can be the possible reason and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would happen if

```
-Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true
```

is passed as a VM parameter to the installer, for example in the "VM parameters" property of the installer.